# Use of quotes for SQL updating to null

Tags: php, sql, null

I have several variables that can contain numbers or be null. And I cannot update the database when the variable is null. I think that the problem is quotes-related, but can't get my way through it. A sample code follows.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "MyUser", "MyPsswrd", "MyDB");  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}   

for ($i = 1; $i <=4; $i++) {
    if (SomeCondition) {
       $Mod[$i]=A_Number_Here;
    } else {
        $Mod[$i]=NULL;
    }
}

$UpD = "UPDATE ".$_SESSION['table']." SET M1=".$Mod[1].", M2=".$Mod[2].", M3=".$Mod[3].", M4=".$Mod[4]." WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";

$link->query($UpD);
```

Comment: Oh my. Please use Prepared Statements and all your problems will go away

Comment: @juergend - not necessarily true. The variables being entered have the value of NULL rather being a MySQL value of NULL that would be understood within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the quotes in the `for` loop.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {
    if (SomeCondition) {
       $Mod[$i]=A_Number_Here;
    }
    else {
        $Mod[$i]="NULL";
    }
}

$UpD="UPDATE ".$_SESSION['table']." SET M1=".$Mod[1].", M2=".$Mod[2].", M3=".$Mod[3].", M4=".$Mod[4]." WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']."";
```

That way the query will use the correct MySQL value of `NULL` and not a PHP variable with the value of `NULL`

Comment: Thanks! And also your answer helps me beyond my specific question, since I need the variable for other php calculations. Its good to know that  "the correct MySQL value of NULL is not a PHP variable with the value of NULL"